# Scraping multiple URLs using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a dataframe with one of the columns containing over 4000 different URLs for articles. I have implemented the following code to extract all the text from the URLs, it seems to work for maybe one or two URLs but does not work for all.

```
for i in df.url:

    http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
    response = http.request('GET', i)
    soup = bsoup(response.data, 'html.parser')


# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
print(text)
break
```

Comment: I have done the following imports for the same:                                                 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import urllib3
import lxml
import html.parser

Answer (score 0):

In the first `for` loop, you are assigning all the parsed urls to the same variable - `soup`. At the end of the loop, this variable will contain the parsed content of the last url and not all the urls as you expected. That's why you are seeing only one output.

You can put all your code in a single loop

```
for url in df.url:
    http = urllib3.PoolManager() 
    response = http.request('GET', url)
    soup = bsoup(response.data, 'html.parser')

    # kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out

    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()

    # break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
    lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())

    # break multi-headlines into a line each
    chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
    # drop blank lines
    text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
    print(url)
    print(text)
```